When I receive a response from Azure OpenAI via the teams ai library, it doesn't show up correctly in Teams
I am creating a TeamsBot app that chats with Azure OpenAI via the Teams AI library.
The response from OpenAI is not displayed correctly in TeamsBot.
I am outputting the response from OpenAI in the log.
We compared the response displayed in the Teams Bot with the log of the TeamsAILibrary.
Comparing the content, the response displayed in TeamsBot is quite short.
It does not happen all the time, but sometimes it does.
I don't know the cause and am having trouble.
I would appreciate your support.[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/tr8D6Z0y.png)

Could you please share the repro steps to try at our end?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
